# When the hard disk of Ubuntu is mounted on the motherboard, the hard disk of Windows 10 does not appear

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, boot-repair

This year I am starting my specialty in Informatics so I thought Ubuntu is a must, but I didn't want to abandon Windows either.
I decided to mount a second NVMe gen3 and dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 (on the computer there is also an HDD just for storage). To do so, I first removed the hard disk that has installed Windows so I would be sure that no partitions of the one OS would appear to the other one. I managed to install Ubuntu and it was working perfectly. I then mounted back the second NVMe with the Windows to verify that the dual boot was working correctly. Things didn't go as expected.

When both hard disks are connected, the hard disk of Windows doesn't appear in the BIOS and I obviously cannot access Windows. When I take out the hard disk of Ubuntu, Windows boots normally. Before installing Ubuntu I verified that my Windows was in UEFI mode so I also installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode. I tried to change the slots just in case but it changed nothing. Then I tried to use in Ubuntu the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and the outcome was this [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5H9MJMNqCT/) that I have to admit, I don't really know for what I should be looking. I also tried the command `sudo update-grub` but once again nothing.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: I also tried this but when I was installing Ubuntu the disk of Windows was **not** appearing again.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. `Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.` prevents `sudo update-grub` from adding,booting Windows from grub. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
Removing a drive, removes the UEFI boot entry. You should just add a new Windows UEFI boot entry. Either using your Windows repair fflash drive or maybe just an efibootmgr entry. See IV: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the users of MSI gaming laptops that has an extra slot for optional SSD be CAREFUL.

MSI in the description of my product (GP63 Leopard 8RE) was only writing "PCI-E Gen.3 SSD (optional)". As I didn't pay that much attention I bought an NVMe Gen 3x4 which wasn't working correctly with my laptop. In fact it was working but my other SSD was disappearing.

After a lot of research and communications with MSI (I want to thank them very much for their help!) I found that the solution was way too simple. Instead of buying an NVMe Gen 3x4, I should have bought an **NVMe Gen 3x2**.